# How can I use this Error handling in Python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add a new error handler but somehow it doesn't work. If the user forgets one of these three arguments, I would like to send a message.

**Code:**

```
async def redeem(ctx, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    allowed_countries = ['US', 'GB', 'DE']
    accounts = []
    keys = []
    country = arg1.upper()
    keyGrab(keys)
    if country in allowed_countries:
        f = open('Accounts/' + str(country) + '.txt', 'r')
        for line in f:
            clean = line.split('\n')
            accounts.append(clean[0])

        f.close()
    if arg1 is None or arg2 is None or arg3 is None
        return await (ctx.send('Please enter in this format ...'))
    if country not in allowed_countries:
        return await (ctx.send('Sorry But the Country you Specified is Not Currently Offered'))
    if arg3 not in keys:
        return await (ctx.send('Sorry but you entered an invalid product key.'))
```

The following is not working:

```
if arg1 is None or arg2 is None or arg3 is None
    return await (ctx.send('Please enter in this format ...'))
```

Everything else is working just fine.

Comment: Is this using [tag:discord.py]? Either way, if you want the arguments to default to `None` if nothing is passed, you need to provide default values in the signature:  `async def redeem(ctx, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None)`

Comment: If you are using discord.py, due to how the arguments are parsed and passed into the function, only the check on `arg3 is None` is really needed. (Assuming `arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None` in the params as per Patrick's comment.)

Comment: @TrebledJ Yes im using Discord.py

Im getting now this error
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/nxk42d

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes im using Discord.py Im getting now this error Screenshot: prntscr.com/nxk42d

Comment: @Beko `arg1.upper()` expects a `str` but without a first argument, the function is called with `arg1 = None`. To get around this, the if-statements should come first, before anything else.

Comment: @TrebledJ oh lol thanks a lot <3

Comment: You should read the documentation on how to lay out commands: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#

Answer (score 0):

Error handling is normally done with `try/except`, it looks like you are just doing boundary checking or input checking. Either way you are missing a `:` at the end of the `if`. Also the `if` statement can be shortened because a `None` value is considered `Falsey`.

```
if arg1 or arg2 or arg3:
    return await (ctx.send('Please enter in this format ...'))
```

Comment: if not (arg1 and arg2 and arg3):
                                   ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

I got this error :(

Comment: @Beko I made a typo (I read your if a little different) so I changed the code. Also I used spaces for my indenting (which I recommend), if you are using tabs then you should tab indent my code.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py offers another way to handle the error without having to manually check each argument by automatically calling [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error), passing along the context and the error raised. A [bunch of different errors](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#exceptions) could be passed in, but the only one that we're really concerned with is [`MissingRequiredArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument), so we'll check for that using an if-statement.

````
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(...)

...

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f'Required arguments are missing for "{ctx.command}". \n'
                       f'```Usage: {ctx.prefix}{ctx.command} {ctx.command.signature}```')

        # you might also like
        # await ctx.send(f'Required arguments are missing for "{ctx.command}". '
        #                f'For help using this command, enter\n```{ctx.prefix}help {ctx.command.qualified_name}```')
````

If you're unfamiliar with some of the statements used above (e.g. `ctx.prefix`, `ctx.command.qualified_name`), it may help to check the documentation for [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context) and [`Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command).

Here, the first `ctx.send` prints a message similar to

> Required arguments are missing for "redeem".
>
> ```
> Usage: !redeem <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>
> ```

The second `ctx.send` prints something like

> Required arguments are missing for "redeem". For help using this command, enter
>
> ```
> !help redeem
> ```

The neat thing about this is that it gets defaulted for all commands. This makes it less tedious for you to have to check each argument.

If you want to check if the error was raised from a particular command, simply nest an if-statement.

```
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        if ctx.command.name == 'redeem':
            # do something special
            ...
```